# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute endswith

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm going to run the following file but I got an error. I don't know how to solve this problem. please guide me.thanks to all.

I got this error:

```
Traceback(most recent call last)    :
  File "scripts/generate_simulated_pair.py", line 55, in <module>
    pair, d.strftime("%Y%m%d")
  File "home/farshad/venv/qsforex/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 77, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

part of my file that error refers to:

```
# Loop over every day in the month and create a CSV file
    # for each day, e.g. "GBPUSD_20150101.csv"
for d in days:
    print(d.day)
    current_time = current_time.replace(day=d.day)
    outfile = open(
        os.path.join(
            settings.CSV_DATA_DIR, 
            "%s_%s.csv" % (
                pair, d.strftime("%Y%m%d")
            )
        ), 
        "w")
    outfile.write("Time,Ask,Bid,AskVolume,BidVolume\n")>
```

my setting.py:

```
from decimal import Decimal
import os


ENVIRONMENTS = { 
"streaming": {
    "real": "stream-fxtrade.oanda.com",
    "practice": "stream-fxpractice.oanda.com",
    "sandbox": "stream-sandbox.oanda.com"
},
"api": {
    "real": "api-fxtrade.oanda.com",
    "practice": "api-fxpractice.oanda.com",
    "sandbox": "api-sandbox.oanda.com"
}
}

CSV_DATA_DIR = os.environ.get('desktop/trading python files/trading      system/qsforex-backtesting-data', None)
OUTPUT_RESULTS_DIR = os.environ.get('desktop/trading python files/trading  system/qsforex-backtesting-results', None)

DOMAIN = "practice"
STREAM_DOMAIN = ENVIRONMENTS["streaming"][DOMAIN]
API_DOMAIN = ENVIRONMENTS["api"][DOMAIN]
ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ.get('OANDA_API_ACCESS_TOKEN', None)
ACCOUNT_ID = os.environ.get('OANDA_API_ACCOUNT_ID', None)

BASE_CURRENCY = "USD"
EQUITY = Decimal("1000.00")
```

Comment: `settings.CSV_DATA_DIR` is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown because `settings.CSV_DATA_DIR`, the first argument to `os.path.join()`, is set to `None`.

It is set to `None` because the environment variable `desktop/trading python files/trading      system/qsforex-backtesting-data` doesn't exist:

```
CSV_DATA_DIR = os.environ.get('desktop/trading python files/trading      system/qsforex-backtesting-data', None)
```

The `os.environ` object is a mapping, and the `.get()` method returns the second argument (`None` here) if the first argument (a key) is not present.